# Bitbake Autotools and Systemd

Tags: autotools, systemd, yocto, bitbake

I am fairly new to yocto and struggling with a recipe which inherits from autotools and systemd.

Systemd is properly set up on the distro, other recipes use it like that but they don't inherit from autotools.

Here is my source code for the recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Single Channel gateway"

LICENSE = "GPLv2" 
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/meta/files/common-licenses/GPL-2.0;md5=801f80980d171dd6425610833a22dbe6"

DEPENDS = "wiringpi"
SRCREV = "c3cf15f6f3db46ec554de873326d253ee0508ea4"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/ArnaudPec/single_chan_pkt_fwd.git;protocol=git;branch=master \
           file://sgw.service"  

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/"

inherit autotools systemd

PARALLEL_MAKE = ""

SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = " sgw.service"

FILES_${PN} += " ${systemd_system_unitdir}/sgw.service"

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/sgw.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
 }
```

Here is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Single Channel Gateway LoRaWAN service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sgw
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

do_package fails with that output:

```
ERROR: sgw-1.0-r0 do_package: SYSTEMD_SERVICE_sgw value sgw.service does not exist
ERROR: sgw-1.0-r0 do_package: Function failed: systemd_populate_packages
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Fl0v0: Fido does not support `${systemd_system_unitdir}`. It is introduced in Jethro.

@helix_: You override autotools's default install function. You should use `do_install_append` instead of `do_install`. Also, you should remove the space before the closing accolade.

```
do_install_append () {
  install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
  install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/sgw.service/ ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
}
```

Comment: Solved it! Thanks a lot